# Evitar que Netbeans remplace asignaciones por getters

Tags: java, netbeans, formato

En ocasiones tengo en Java algo como lo siguiente :

```
public class MiClase {
    Objeto objeto;

    Objeto objeto2;

    public void foo() {
        objeto = new Objet();
        objeto2 = objeto;
    }

    public Objeto getObjeto2() {
        return objeto2;
    }

    public void setObjeto2(Objeto objeto2) {
        this.objeto2 = objeto2;
    }
}
```

Pero cuando uso `alt+shif+f` para ordenar el código me remplaza las asignaciones a lo siguiente:

```
public class MiClase {
    Objeto objeto;

    Objeto objeto2;

    public void foo() {
        objeto = new Objet();
        setObjeto2(objeto);
    }

    public Objeto getObjeto2() {
        return objeto2;
    }

    public void setObjeto2(Objeto objeto2) {
        this.objeto2 = objeto2;
    }
}
```

Lo cual me es bastante incómodo, ¿Hay una forma de evitar eso en Netbeans?

Ya busqué en opciones pero no encontré nada relacionado.

Comment: Has probado alt+shif+f  en mi caso ctrl+shift+f es para buscar coincidencias.

Comment: @Crack81 Tienes razón, escribí mal el el shortcut, ya lo edité

Comment: Bueno, entonces tu pregunta no tiene un problema de desarrollo que resolver... |

Comment: @Jorgesys No, no lo es. Es una pregunta acerca de editar la configuración de netbeans.

Comment: @gibranalexismorenozuñiga No hace *eso* que dice en NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101). ¿Qué version tienes?

Comment: @PaulVargas 8.2 development version